# Fetching only first row value in Database

Tags: php, database, pdo

We are trying to fetch value from database & display related value for all rows.

but code is fetching only **first row** value in DB & displaying same value for **all rows**.

**Database**

[image]

**Site**

[image]

```
function getDesignerCollection()
    {
    $i = 0;

    foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems);
        $k = 0;

        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))
            {

              if($data['dpaid_status']=='P'){$dpaid_status='Paid';}
              if($data['dpaid_status']=='U'){$dpaid_status='Unpaid';}
              if($data['dpaid_status']=='R'){$dpaid_status='Returned';}
              if($data['dpaid_status']==''){$dpaid_status='';}

            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0')
                {
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(
                    ":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']
                ));
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = "Unpaid";
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status'];
                    }

                $responce[] = array(
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderitemsarray[$k],
                    $dorderStatus                               
                );
                }

            $k++;
            $i++;
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($responce);
    }
```

full code : http://pastebin.com/GnT980nL

Comment: Call `fetch()` in a loop to get all the rows.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, i am new to php, please tell what code i have to try ?

Comment: I think for every query ' ":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id'] ' is going same id thats why it return matching first row, may you check your order array has different orders.

Comment: Read any tutorial on using MySQL from PHP, they show how to do it.

Comment: `while ($roworders = $stmtorder->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }`

Comment: There's no `:dorder_id` placeholder in the query, why are you passing that in the call to `execute()`?

Comment: The query should be `SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE order_id = :dorder_id`

Comment: @Barmar when i tried  `while ($roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    
    {
    
    if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
     {
     $dorderStatus = "Unpaid";
     }
      else
     {
     $dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status'];
     } }`     now its displaying  `last row` value `R` for all rows.....

Comment: You need to push into the response array inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @Barmar when i replaced this code : `SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dorder_id = :dorder_id` it didt displayed any values.....

Comment: @Barmar when i pushed `response array` inside `while loop` , now for one row in db, its displaying all 3 rows in site with values `P, U, R` . `while ($roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))   
    {   
    if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
     {
     $dorderStatus = "Unpaid";
     }
      else
     {
     $dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status'];
     }       
     $responce[] = array(                   
                    $dorderStatus                               
                );
                }

            $k++;
            $i++;
   }
    }`

Comment: Well, if you don't do that, you'll show details of ALL orders, not just the ones in `$order`.

Comment: @Barmar i need to show details of all orders. can you please check code in above comment , its displaying [db](1) = > (site)(3) values......

Comment: You need to show the details of all orders multiple times? Because you're doing it repeatedly for each order in `$order`, and then for each item in `$orderitemsarray`. So if there are 10 orders in `$order`, and each of them has 5 items, you'll show every order detail 50 times.

Comment: @Barmar than i dont need that, but when i try `SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dorder_id = :dorder_id` its not displaying any values [ order grid table].....

Comment: Then there's something wrong with `$orderData['entity_id']`, since it doesn't match what's in the table. Are you sure that's the correct array element to use for this?

Comment: @Barmar we have 2 Databases, we are fetching some information for 1st DB , there we have `entity_id` column, but we are trying to fetch `Paid status` from 2nd DB.

so we are using `$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE dorder_id = :dorder_id");` , do you think that is the problem ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where `$oderData` came from.

Comment: @Barmar please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders.php) email : kidsdial1@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial1 [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders.php)

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to tell from going there. I can't see the PHP code, just the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130086/discussion-between-abcd-and-barmar).

Comment: @user34613 please tell `how to  check order array has different orders.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `fetchAll()` instead `fetch()`

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Your function must looks like:

```
function getDesignerCollection() {
    global $is_admin;
    $user_home = new USER();
    require_once '../../app/Mage.php';

    Mage::app();

    $stmts = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmts->execute(array(
        ":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']
    ));
    $rows = $stmts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Now in `$rows` you have array of associative arrays.

Comment: i changed as you said, now its not fetching any value instead its displaying `Unpaid` for all rows, as we have this code : `if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
     {
     $dorderStatus = "Unpaid";
     }`

Comment: You need change your code. Don't use query to DB in loop, it's bad practice.

Comment: In your full code you wrote right. Just change in 62 line.